# How can I make Google authentication prompt the user to pick an account when she has multiple accounts active (on mobile)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-authentication

I have an AppEngine (Java) application that uses the native AppEngine authentication mechanism (see: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/users/).  It generates login and logout URLs via the `createLoginURL` and `createLogoutURL` methods as detailed in that article.

On desktop, everything works perfectly fine.  A user with multiple accounts active will be prompted to select one to use upon login, and she will be logged out of all of her accounts upon logout.

On mobile, however, it does not work this way.  A user with multiple accounts will be automatically signed in to the first one (whatever that is) upon login, and she will be prompted to choose an account upon logout.  I have no idea *why* the account-picker is shown as part of the logout process, and I have no idea what choosing an account there actually does, since the end-result appears to be the same regardless of the account chosen: AppEngine thinks that the user has been signed out.

In the past, an account picker used to be shown upon login (it was a radio-button account picker, less pretty than the logout one, but functional nonetheless).  Now, I cannot get one to appear.  I have confirmed via https://myaccount.google.com that multiple accounts are actively signed in.

A simple test of this workflow is as follows:

1. Generate login and logout URLs via `createLoginURL` and `createLogoutURL`.
2. On *mobile*:

   1. Sign in with one Google account.
   2. Sign in with another Google account.
   3. Confirm that both are signed in via https://myaccount.google.com.
   4. Navigate to the login URL.

      1. Expected behavior: account picker is shown; upon selection, the user is redirected to the "continue" URL.
      2. Actual behavior: no user action takes place and the user is redirected to the "continue" URL.
   5. Navigate to the logout URL.

      1. Expected behavior: no user action takes place and the user is redirected to the "continue" URL.
      2. Actual behavior: account picker is shown; upon selection, the user is redirected to the "continue" URL.

For reference, here are the values of the login and logout URLs as generated by the `createLoginURL` and `createLogoutURL` methods (obviously "EXAMPLE-APP" would be the actual AppEngine ID of my application):

- `createLoginUrl("/ui/signin.html")`: `https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps://EXAMPLE-APP.appspot.com/ui/signin.html&ltmpl=gm`
- `createLogoutUrl("/ui/signout.html")`: `https://EXAMPLE-APP.appspot.com/_ah/logout?continue=https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout%253Fcontinue%253Dhttps://EXAMPLE-APP.appspot.com/ui/signout.html%26service%3Dah`

Also, I am currently experiencing this with Android phones running Chrome (one Galaxy S6 and one Pixel; I do not have other devices to test with at this time).

My question: how can I make Google display the account picker for the login action in Google AppEngine (for Java) on mobile devices?

**Edit:** Here is an example AppEngine project that demonstrates the problem.

- Site: https://java-auth-test.appspot.com/
- Source: https://github.com/tekkamanendless/appengine-java-auth-test/blob/master/src/main/webapp/index.jsp

Comment: I'm seeing this same behavior.  Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Nope; no progress :(